# Odd use of curly braces in C

Tags: objective-c, c, initialization, structure

Sorry for the simple question but I'm on vacation reading a book on core audio, and don't have my C or Objective C books with me...

What are the curly braces doing in this variable definition?

```
MyRecorder recorder = {0};
```

Comment: I like to call the `{0}`, the ***universal zero initializer***. It "works", recursively if needed, for every type! ints, doubles, structs, arrays, pointers, pointers to structs, structs with arrays of pointers, ..., ...

Comment: @pmg — why didn't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: My comment really isn't an answer: it doesn't explain anything, it merely points out another use of the construct --- and the name I give that construct. Also explaining how `{0}` is different to `{42}` and how they apply to arrays or nested structs or other "strange" types would require a very long answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming that `MyRecorder` is a `struct`, this [sets every member to their respective representation of zero](http://ex-parrot.com/~chris/random/initialise.html) (`0` for integers, `NULL` for pointers etc.).

Actually this also works on all other datatypes like `int`, `double`, pointers, arrays, nested structures, ..., everything you can imagine (thanks to pmg for pointing this out!)

**UPDATE**: A quote extracted from the website linked above, citing the final draft of C99:

> [6.7.8.21] If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list
>   than there are elements or members of an aggregate, [...] the remainder of the
>   aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that
>   have static storage duration.

Comment: struct members do not have default values: it may be better to say zero explicitly --- "sets every member to (the right kind of) zero".

Answer (score 9):

Its initializing *all* members of `recorder` structure to `0` according to C99 standard.  It might seem that it initializes every bit of the structure with `0` bits. But thats not true for every compiler.

See this example code,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s {
    int i;
    unsigned long l;
    double d;
};

int main(){
    struct s es = {0};
    printf("%d\n", es.i);
    printf("%lu\n", es.l);
    printf("%f\n", es.d);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output.

```
$ ./a.out 
0
0
0.000000
```

Comment: "Its initializing all members of recorder structure to 0." is in application of the C99 standard. "In fact it initialize every bit of the structure with 0 bits." is only true in practice on conventional architectures, and the C99 standard points out several times that it is not saying that it is true, and that a standard-conforming compiler/target architecture do not have to make it true.

Answer (score 5):

It is [an initialization of a structure](http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/c-structure-initialization-advanced/).

Comment: could also be of a scalar: `MyRecorder recorder = {0};` where `MyRecorder` is an alias of `int` for example is valid in C

Comment: @ouah Judging from the name of the `struct`, I say it is *highly unlikely* that it is an `int` or in fact anything other than a structure/union.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it don't initliaze all the elements of the structure, just the first one. But, the others are automatically initialized with 0 because this is what the C standard ask to do.

If you put:
MyRecorder recorder = {3};

The first element will be 3 and the others weill be 0.

Answer (score 0):

`MyRecorder` could be one of the following and you are attempting to initialize all the elements of that with zero

```
typedef struct _MyRecorder1 {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
}MyRecorder1;

typedef int MyRecorder2[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C++11, in C99 there has to be at least one element in initializer braces.

C++11 struct:

```
MyRecorder recorder{};
```

C struct:

```
MyRecorder recorder = {0};
```